# Drawing oval in ArcGIS CityEngine

Tags: arcgis-desktop, cityengine, drawing

How do I draw an oval, or modify a circle to become an oval, using CityEngine?

I have been able to draw ovals using CGA code but would like to just draw one using shape tools and modification tools.

Comment: Thanks for that Kinan, but I was looking for a solution from within CityEngine, i.e. not having to draw the ellipse in ArcMap then bring it into CityEngine but actually drawing the oval right in CityEngine or at least drawing a circle then modifying it to an oval.

Answer (score 3):

in ArcGIS Desktop [in ArcMap], when start editing (Drawing Polygon) there is **Ellipse** choice.

[image]